# How to get to join table Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

My model:

```
        public function category($column, $value)
{
    $this->db->select('c.cat2, c.category, m.id, m.date, m.when_date, m.when_time, m.where_m, m.age1, m.age2, m.opis, m.rozpoznamy');
    $this->db->from('category c');
    $this->db->where($column, $value);
    $this->db->join('meeting m', 'm.id_cat = c.id');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();
}
        public function delete($where, $column, $value)
{
    $this->db->delete($this->users_m->category($column, $value), $where);
}
```

My controler:

```
    public function delete()
{
    $cat = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $value = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $column = 'm.id';
    $where = array('m.id' => $value);
    $this->users_m->delete($where, $column, $value);
    redirect('main/category/' . $cat);
}
```

I have problem to delete data from join table, get this message when I try delete:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table 'ci.object' doesn't exist
>
> DELETE FROM `Object` WHERE `m`.`id` = '13'
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

So probably theres a problem with table in function delete. I try on different ways to get to this table and I don't know how to solve this. Any clue?

Comment: Error says everything "Table 'ci.object' doesn't exist".Make sure that table exist!!!

Comment: I know that, but i thing problem is here: 

$this->db->delete($this->users_m->category($column, $value), $where);
specyfic here: $this->users_m->category($column, $value)

Im trying to get to join table from other function(category) in this model. And maybe i bad recant to this table

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a CI Object into `$this->db->delete()` as `$this->users_m->category()` returns a DB result array of object(s).

CI Delete works by passing in the table name, in your case it looks like it will be

```
 public function delete($where) {
     $this->db->where('meeting m', $where);
     $this->db->delete('meeting');
 }
```

I can't work out why you have extra values in there

Comment: still the problem:

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm WHERE `m`.`id` = '13'' at line 1

DELETE FROM `meeting` m WHERE `m`.`id` = '13'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

But change to:
public function delete($where) {
     $this->db->delete('meeting m', $where);
 }

Comment: ok figure it out change to:
public function delete($where) {
     $this->db->delete('meeting', $where);
 }
and in controler:
$where = array('id' => $value);
and now works, thanks ;)